# getQueryPredictions Api is failing to fetch the address for formatted address

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Im using `AutocompeteSerive` to fetch address from Google `getQueryPredictions` API.

Here is the init of autocomplete input box:

```
this.autoComp = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService({
    componentRestrictions: { 'country': 'in' }
});

this.autoComp.getQueryPredictions({ input: value }, (results, status) => {
    console.log(status);
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {}
})
```

Step 1:

**User enters bangalore**.

Select the below predication for Google Api:

> No. 15, Mysuru Road, Near, Temple, Pancha Mukhi Ganapati Mandir, Kengeri, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560060, India

Resend this address to same api for user confirmation :
ZERO_RESULTS

Any solutions ?

Note : tried to send same address twice to this below api its working fine..;(

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=No.%2015,%20Mysuru%20Road,%20Near,%20Temple,%20Pancha%20Mukhi%20Ganapati%20Mandir,%20Kengeri,%20Bengaluru,%20Karnataka%20560060,%20India&sensor=false&key=xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Use the `placeId` instead of the full address in your Geocoder request. Everything is explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#place-id).

Comment: Re-reading your question, if you didn't want to use the Geocoder, you could do the same by getting the [place details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details), that is, by providing the `placeId`.

Comment: True , i'm not persisting place id due to space constraint . re-reading of results are  very sporodic , ~65% address are re calculating but only ~35% are failing..

Comment: I don't get your comment. `getQueryPredictions` returns the `placeId` as well.

Comment: use case is like user selects address and after some days if he comes back with same address , i have to suggest this address in autocomplete. rather showing Zero-results.  maintaining PlaceId will be bit costly for me as there will be million hits

Comment: I don't see how storing an id would be worse than storing a complete address... You could store it for some time only. And you could store it in a cookie / in the browser too. That's what cookies / local storage are for.

Comment: True, But Here issue is not storing id  rather figuring out  why 65% of address are re-calculated and why not for all.? any options can be sent to google api?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *re-calculated*. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.